# Add default timestamp function as a default value using terraform chanzuckerberg snowflake provider

Tags: terraform

I am trying to create a table and for the column I want to give the default value as current timestamp. What am I doing wrong here?
Ref -
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/chanzuckerberg/snowflake/latest/docs/resources/table

```
resource "snowflake_table" "snow_events_table" {
  database        = "SNOW"
  schema          = "PUBLIC"
  name            = "SNOW_EVENTS"
  comment         = "Events from S3 are transformed into this table"
  cluster_by      = ["org_id"]
  change_tracking = false

  column {
    name     = "_date_created"
    type     = "TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9)"
    nullable = false

    default {
      expression = "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()"
    }
  }
}
```

Error is

```
Error: Unsupported block type │  │   on ../../modules/snowplow-s3-storage/tables.tf line 21, in resource "snowflake_table" "snow_events_table": │   21:     default { │  │ Blocks of type "default" are not expected here.
```

Comment: We need more information. When you try to init, plan, and apply this, what is the error you're facing?

Comment: @JakeNelson When I run the plan, here is the error -
```╷
│ Error: Unsupported block type
│ 
│   on ../../modules/snowplow-s3-storage/tables.tf line 21, in resource "snowflake_table" "snow_events_table":
│   21:     default {
│ 
│ Blocks of type "default" are not expected here.
```

Comment: Docs and provider code suggest it's supported. Can you give us even more info? e.g. Terraform version and provider version?

Comment: I'm actually trying this just now which version of the provider are you using?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?